# Confusion on equivalence class $[a]=${$(x_a,z);∀z∈C$} meaning

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, notation, equivalence-relations

For an equivalence class $[a] = \{ (x_a,z) : z \in C \}$ means $[a] = \{x_a\} \times C$ where $z∈C$? Am I defining it correctly?

Comment: Yes, as you wrote.

Comment: Though in builder notation I'd rather write $\{\,(x_a,z)\mid z\in C\,\}$

Comment: Thanks for confirming this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid characterization: all these are equivalent:

$$\{(x_a,z)\mid \forall z \in C \} = \{x_a \} \times C = \{(x_a,z)\mid z \in C\}$$

That said, I would prefer one of the latter two notations (which I'd use depending on context). The latter seems a more "proper" setbuilder notation for the set you're describing.

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*